# How to conditionally abort a minor-mode invocation?

Tags: minor-mode

I have a minor mode definition like this, and I want to prevent it from being enabled when the config variable `example-mode-config` has not been defined.

```
;;; ....

;;;###autoload
(define-minor-mode example-mode
  "Enables the example mode"
  (if example-mode
      (example-mode-enable)
    (example-mode-disable)))

(defun example-mode-enable ()
  (cond ((not example-mode-config)
         (message "please define example-mode-config before using example-mode")
         ;;; seem to need to do something here to disable the mode
         ;;; otherwise the mode gets enabled, but does not work
         )
        (t  ;;;; go ahead and set up .....
         )))
```

The problem is that if `example-mode-config` is undefined, the function `example-mode-config` returns doing nothing, but the calling framework still goes ahead and enables the mode.

Comment: If by "undefined" you mean `example-mode-config` might not yet be *bound*, you can test that with `boundp`.

Comment: Yes, although in my case it has been declared with `defcustom` but set to nil, and `boundp` returns `t`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way to do that is simply to set `example-mode` within the minor mode's body (also I find it's rarely useful to have separate `foo-enable` and `foo-disable` functions):

```
(define-minor-mode example-mode
  "Enables the example mode"
  (cond
   ((not example-mode-config)
    (setq example-mode nil)
    (message "Set example-mode-config before using example-mode"))
   (example-mode
    ...go ahead and set it up...)
   (t
    ...disable the mode...))
```

If you want to avoid the execution of the `example-mode-hook` functions on a missing configuration just change the first `message` into `error` for a non-local exit.

Comment: Setting `example-mode` to nil does not prevent the execution of the hook functions even if the mode was never active. I think you need at least a non-local exit for that. (You never know what users do within the hook functions. It might be that they assume that `example-mode` was t if the hook function is called with a nil value for `example-mode`. That could cause access of void values and stuff like that.)

Comment: @Tobias: the hook function of minor modes is run both when enabling and disabling the mode, including when enabling a mode that was already enabled and disabling a mode that was already disabled, so I don't see any reason why we should make extra efforts to avoid running the hook. But if you want that, just change the `message` into `error`.

Comment: Okay I think I see what you mean. One can just run `(example-mode -1)` to make sure that `example-mode` is not active regardless of the value of `example-mode`. Good. One needs to keep that in mind when one writes hook functions for minor-modes. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: What works for me is, when `example-mode-config` is not configured, to `(example-mode -1)` then `(error "Set...")` - this seems to successfully prevent example-mode getting marked enabled in the status line.

Comment: @wo-lee That is what I thought when I wrote up my solution after inspecting the code of `define-minor-mode`. Should I undelete my solution? Before I thought about the indicator in the mode line and the hook functions I tented to give Stefans solution of just setting the mode variable to nil. I re-thought after inspecting the code. Afterwards I read Stefan's solution. Stefan is generally more experienced than me. Therefore I accepted his simple solution and deleted mine.

Comment: @Tobias - feel free to undelete or modify your solution as you see fit. I saw it briefly, then it disappeared. As I couldn't check or compare it fully, I can't really comment further.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: The answer of Stefan is right and it is good that you accepted it.

I re-visited the code of `define-minor-mode`. Maybe a small modification of your code is in place. So go on reading...

The structure of the generated mode-function `example-mode` is as follows:

1. Setting the mode-variable
2. Running `body`
3. Running the hook(s)
4. Printing a message when called interactively
5. Mode line update.

So it seems best to handle a configuration error as follows in the `body`:

1. Set the mode variable back.
2. Call `(error ...)` to avoid the message and the mode-line-update.
   In the normal case you don't need the mode-line-update since the value of the mode variable was right (nil) before the call of the mode function.

If you want to allow a failing **re-configuration** through a call to `(example-mode)` even if `example-mode` is already t at invocation of `(example-mode)` add a `(force-mode-line-update)` after `(setq example-mode nil)` in the error case.

Since you are effectively switching off `example-mode` in the case of a configuration error it may even be good to call the mode hooks. So the only thing we avoid is the message.